# Run multiple Javascript functions from drop-down onchange menu

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have different JS functions...

```
function stores(NY)
{
blah, blah, blah...
}
function stores(CA)
{
blah, blah, blah...
}
function stores(FL)
{
blah, blah, blah...
}
```

And I wish to run them from this drop-down menu...

```
<select onchange="stores(this.value);">
<option>Please select your state from this list...</option>
<option value="NY">New York</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="FL">Florida</option>
</select>
```

And so on up to 50 US States, that's why I need a simple way to call these functions but this is not working. Any ideas will be much appreciated. Thank y'all in advanced!

Comment: Please choose a best answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need one function.

```
function stores(city) {
  if (city === 'NY') {
    //blah, blah, blah...
  } else if (city === 'CA') {
    //blah, blah, blah...
  } else if (...) {
    // ... and so on
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to create an object literal whose *keys* in their key-value pairs are the names by which to call the functions.

```
var methods = {
    "NY": function() {},
    "CA": function() {},
    "FL": function() {}
};

element.onchange = function() {
    methods[ this[ this.selectedIndex ].value ]();
};
```

This concept gets rid of if and case statements and is object-oriented. We programmatically issue the event handler and call the function based on the value of the element's selected index.

Comment: This would be a good way _so long as the logic is different in the functions_.  If the logic is the same but the data is different then the shared logic should be consolidated and object could represent the data difference.

Comment: The logic *will* be different because he wanted separate functions for each of them. If the `value` of the selected index doesn't make a difference, then he wouldn't have made different functions for each of them. But that's only assuming the OP knows what he's doing.

Comment: It's impossible to say without any of the function body shown, but from the name of the function it looks like they may only vary by the data returned.  My comment was directed to the OP for that case, not as a critique on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by switch case

```
function stores(city) {

switch(city){
 case 'NY':
    //your stuf
    break;
  case 'CA':
    //your stuf
   break;
  case 'FL':
    //your stuf
   break;
 default:
   code to be executed if n is different from above all case
  }

}
```